# ERROR: Failed to restart "apache": cannot start service: AH00543: httpd: bad user name on MacOs Catalina when adding virtual host

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost, macos-catalina

I am adding a virtual host on my xampp. When virtual host is added then it's not accessible and give 403 Access forbidden!.

It's solution is change username to mac username. But when I change username to

```
User mujahidfarooq
Group mujahidfarooq
```

I get

```
ERROR: Failed to restart "apache": cannot stop service: AH00543: httpd: bad user name mujahidfarooq
```

Now if I change user to `daemon` I am unable to access and get 403 Error and If I change user to mac username then apatche doesn't start with `AHAH00543` Error.

I am looking for solution. Have tried all ways but didn't find anything.

My code to add virtual host is:

```
# My custom host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myecommerce.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/mac/Documents/Web-Development/Ecommerce-project"
    <Directory "/Users/mac/Documents/Web-Development/Ecommerce-project">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/myecommerce.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you give r+w permissions to the folder located at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/lang.tmp.`

Comment: I really don't find this file whenever I write path to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/`
terminal says no such file or folder exist

Comment: does this link help you https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/

Comment: I setuped my virtual host using this link. The issue is, when I change user from daemon to mujahidfarooq. xampp gives apatche error as bad username and on user daemon xampp is inaccessible with 403 Error

Comment: Judging from your paths your username is `mac` as far as system is concerned - `/Users/Mac/`

Comment: I will change it and get back to you.